# User gets the UserId of the previously logged in user

Tags: java

I have an understanding problem with static variables in Java.
The following scenario:

I have a login page, a user logs in, I read the credentials as Json web tokens using a request.getHeader ("auth") and save the UserID (e.g. MaxMustermann) in a global static variable.

So far so good - now the problem is that when another user logs in and makes a change in the application, he has the UserId of the previously logged in user.

How can that be ? Each user has his own network structure.

Here is my class, which saves the global user ID of the respective logged-in user:

```
public class Anwender {

public static String userId = "";

public static String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public static void setUserId(String userId) {
    Anwender.userId = userId;
}

}
```

Comment: Do you change the ID when a new user logs in ? with `setUserId`

Comment: Yes. But only once. A user logs in via a registration mask (OAUTH) and I save the UserId using the setUserId method in the static variable.
That pairs with every user who logs on

Comment: Why once ? Why not on each new login ?

Comment: I do.
Every user who logs in is saved in this global variable. Each session for itself.

Comment: Why the userId is kept as static and public, if so then there is no need of getters and setters.. this class is an inappropriate class in java, because encapsulation fails here..

Comment: @Jagadesh So what would your suggestion be? I need the UserId for database queries. Therefore also the storage in a global variable

Comment: If you are using same class for DAO and DTO, then separate and remove the static form userId and make it as private..

Comment: @Jagadesh The user class is in a different package than all other classes that make a database call.

Comment: When you say "Each session for itself", do you mean a new running java program or do the different users share this java program? The "static" keyword means this is a global variable on the class level. Every instance will see the same value for this variable. (Other threads may still see an old value, as this implementation doesn't seem to be thread-safe)

Comment: @Scratte No, every user gets his own session and thus his own user ID globally as soon as he logs in (at least that's the plan, which is not working as it should).

Comment: How do they get their own session? I asked an "either or" question for clarification. You just replied with "No".. "No" to what? Does the same java program run with every session? **OR** do you start a new java program for every session? What code do you use when a user logs in? Do you create a new `Anwender` class? Do you call the `setUserId` method? Do you create a new thread within the same program? What does "Each user has his own network structure" mean?

Comment: Perhaps Oracle's Java tutorial on [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) will be helpful to you.